# ZXingQR Codescanner should open a new Activity

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

**My idea is when i scan a definite QR code, the app open a new Activity
What kind of command I need?**

The Activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.c_wall);





    }
    public void onClick (View view){
        IntentIntegrator integrator =new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.initiateScan();
}
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanResult != null){
            {

    }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear of what you are trying to achieve. Please add more information.

Comment: The app is for a child's birthday. The children run at different coordinates and need to scan a QR code. Have they scanned the QR code, a new activity opens with a new job and a new coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a new activity when a QRCode has been scanned, you must use an intent in the onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanResult != null){
               Intent newactivity = new Intent(ThisClass.this, NextActivity.class);
               startActivity(newactivity);
        }

    }
```

If you want to parse or validate the scaned QRcode first, you can do the following:

```
String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
```

Then you can compare contents with your expected string:

```
if(contents.equals("CorrectScan")) { .......
```